# I get the message cannot set using a list-like indexer with a different length than value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I am trying to assign a new value to a pandas Dataframe called `df` with this code:

```
df.loc[ (~df['col1'].str.contains("|".join(df['col2']))) & (df['col2'] == 'both') & (df['col3'] != ''), 'col2'] = df['col1'].astype(str) + " || " + df['col2'].astype(str)
```

But when I execute it, I get the error:

> cannot set using a list-like indexer with a different length than value

When I print the length of the array that is produced from the condition and the length of `df`, they are the same.

Comment: Will you please send a small sample of your dataframe? (`print(df.head().to_dict())`)

Comment: Maybe you should do `df['col2'].str.join("|")` instead of  `"|".join(df['col2'])`